# setValue method or property not found while implementing LibreOffice Calc Macro

Tags: macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, basic

I am using LibreOffice Calc over 3 years now, but recently started implementing Macros using Basic. I have referred to online resources relevant to Libreoffice Calc Macro and I am trying to get a absolute file path in a specific cell.

Following is the code I am trying to run, which throws me error:

**Error:**

> BASIC runtime error.
>
> Property or method not found: setValue.

**Code**

```
Sub selectFile

    Dim FileNames() as String
    Dim Doc         as Object
    Dim oSheet      as Object
    Dim oDestCell   as Object

    FileNames = fImportLocalFile()

    Doc = ThisComponent
    oSheet = Doc.Sheets(0)
    oDestCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(1,1)
    oSheet.setValue(FileNames, False)
    Msgbox Join(FileNames, Chr(10))

End Sub
```

I may be missing some import/include which is leading to this error. Unable to find relevant resource online and hence posting my question here.

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: I have also tried following:

1) oDestCell.Value = FileNames
Error:
BASIC runtime error.
Object variable not set.

2) oDestCell.Text = FileNames
Read-Error.
This property is read-only.

Comment: Please consider using `StackOverflow` next time for this type of question(s), as it seems more appropriate.  `SU` = user's questions, `SO` = "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Answer (score 0):

For programming of LibreOffice/Apache OpenOffice get the Extension `MRI`!
As well as the documentation (can be found in the `SDK` installation packages).

This is what **`MRI`** recorded for your goal:

```
Sub Snippet
  Dim oSheets As Variant
  Dim oObj1 As Variant
  Dim oCellByPosition As Variant

  oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
  oObj1 = oSheets.getByName("Tabelle1")
  oCellByPosition = oObj1.getCellByPosition(1, 1)
  oCellByPosition.setString("whatever")

End Sub
```

**Explanation**:

`sheet.setValue` - as the error message stated: there is no such property.
`cell.Value` - error, as `.setValue` sets a `DOUBLE`, not a string.
`cell.Text` - error, as a cell's `Text` object needs a `CellTextCursor` (which holds formatting instructions) and a `String` (holding the text characters).

As a starter get [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), as a free document - or buy his book.
[I'm not connected to the author or proceedings of his book]